# Checking if imageView is empty with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have database table, there is a column "image_link", so when I open activity, class Picasso get this image_link and show me image. But now I also may have path to image in my column instead of imageLink, but I need show image in any case, I think that it will work if I will do something like that:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.get().load(favouriteTemplates.get(position).getImageLink()).into(holder.icon);
        if(holder.icon.getDrawable() == null){
            Picasso.get().load(new File(favouriteTemplates.get(position).getImageLink())).into(holder.icon);
        }
    }
```

But I know, that it takes some time to download image into imageview with Picasso, so my "if"  always is true. How can I solve it?

Comment: simply check string is empty or not before adding url in Picasso

Comment: favouriteTemplates.get(position).getImageLink() check this url is empty or not

Comment: you can use placeholder after into method you can write .placeholder(R.drawable."somephoto you want") you can use that if you want to use somephoto if an error occurs

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.get()
   .load(favouriteTemplates.get(position).getImageLink())
   .into(holder.icon),
      new Callback() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess() {
               //Do Nothing
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(Exception e) {
              Picasso
              .get()
              .load(newmFile(favouriteTemplates.get(position).getImageLink()))
              .into(holder.icon);
           }
      }
   );
```

Comment: Images from internet is shown, but images from my gallery isnt. It's my path to image, because inError method isnt called